# Swift array messing with the release of weak variables

Tags: arrays, swift, automatic-ref-counting, reference-counting

Swift arrays is that they are value types while classes are reference types, so I thought having something like `[SomeClass]` would create an array containing the references to `SomeClass` instances.

However, in Swift REPL, the following happens:

```
  1> class SomeClass {}
  2> var obj: SomeClass? = SomeClass()
obj: SomeClass? = 0x0000000101100050
  3> weak var weakObj = obj
weakObj: SomeClass? = 0x0000000101100050
  4> var array = [SomeClass?]()
array: [SomeClass?] = 0 values
  5> array.append(obj)
  6> print(obj, weakObj)
Optional(SomeClass) Optional(SomeClass)
  7> array.removeFirst()
$R0: SomeClass? = 0x0000000101100050
  8> obj = nil
  9> print(obj, weakObj)
nil Optional(SomeClass)
 10> print(array)
[]
 11> print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(weakObj!).toOpaque())
0x0000000101100050
```

I thought the reference count of the instance at `0x0000000101100050` should be 2 after appending `obj` to `array`, and once `obj = nil` and `array.removeFirst()` were called, both references were removed, therefore the instance should be released.

However, this doesn't seem to be the case. Without the array part, `obj` is released like it should. What am I missing here?

**ADDED**
It seems like there is something going on with `removeFirst()`, `popLast()` and similar functions. (Possibly a bug?)

Setting the object at the array index directly to `nil` works just fine.

```
 102> obj = SomeClass()
 103> (weakObj, array) = (obj, [obj])
 104> print(obj, weakObj, array)
Optional(SomeClass) Optional(SomeClass) Optional([Optional(SomeClass)])
 105> obj = nil
 106> array?[0] = nil
$R14: ()? = nil
 107> print(obj, weakObj, array)
nil nil Optional([nil])
```

However, when using `removeLast()` or `popLast()`, `weakObj` will be released only when `array` itself is released.

Comment: I think `$R0` might be holding a strong reference

Comment: When you remove from the array, the `removeFirst` function is returning you the object that was removed. This is strongly referenced by `$R0`, keeping your object alive. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `array.removeFirst()` on line `7` is returning the object that was removed. The repl assigns this to `$R0` for you, which is the strong reference keeping your object alive.

Your code behaves as you expect if you explicitly discard the result with `_ =`:

```
Welcome to Apple Swift version 3.0.1 (swiftlang-800.0.58.6 clang-800.0.42.1). Type :help for assistance.
  1> class SomeClass {}
  2> var obj: SomeClass? = SomeClass()
obj: SomeClass? = 0x00000001006005b0
  3> weak var weakObj = obj
weakObj: SomeClass? = 0x00000001006005b0
  4> var array = [SomeClass?]()
array: [SomeClass?] = 0 values
  5> array.append(obj)
  6> print(obj, weakObj)
Optional(SomeClass) Optional(SomeClass)
  7> _ = array.removeFirst()
  8> obj = nil
  9> print(obj, weakObj)
nil nil
 10> print(array)
[]
 11> print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(weakObj!).toOpaque())
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2016-11-27 20:58:42.066831 repl_swift[62143:10516084] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
Current stack trace:
0    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001002bccc0 swift_reportError + 132
1    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001002da070 _swift_stdlib_reportFatalError + 61
2    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001000d00a0 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 355
3    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x000000010024c210 partial apply for (_fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never).(closure #2) + 109
4    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001000d00a0 specialized specialized StaticString.withUTF8Buffer<A> ((UnsafeBufferPointer<UInt8>) -> A) -> A + 355
5    libswiftCore.dylib                 0x00000001002043d0 specialized _fatalErrorMessage(StaticString, StaticString, StaticString, UInt, flags : UInt32) -> Never + 96
7    repl_swift                         0x0000000100001420 main + 0
8    libdyld.dylib                      0x00007fffaaec7254 start + 1
Execution interrupted. Enter code to recover and continue.
Enter LLDB commands to investigate (type :help for assistance.)
 12>
```

Comment: I guess I should read up on how the REPL works. Didn't know `$R0` was a thing you could reference in the REPL.

Comment: Yeah, it's really handy. If you don't assign the result of an expression to a variable (or discard it with `_`), then the REPL creates a new `$R` variable for you. It can be very handy to use a value from the past that you didn't think you'd want to use

Comment: @BridgeTheGap Have I answered your question?

Comment: Oops. Forgot to check.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, REPL (or Playground) is not a good place to experiment how Swift ARC are working.

Tried your code as a Command Line project of macOS:

```
import Foundation

class SomeClass {}
var obj: SomeClass? = SomeClass()
weak var weakObj = obj
var array = [SomeClass?]()
array.append(obj)
print(obj, weakObj) //->Optional(SwiftArrayARC.SomeClass) Optional(SwiftArrayARC.SomeClass)
array.removeFirst()
obj = nil
print(obj, weakObj) //->nil nil
print(array) //->[]
print(Unmanaged.passUnretained(weakObj!).toOpaque()) //=>fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Isn't this what you expect?

REPL may keep strong references for the results of each line to enable you to use them later, so, in REPL environment, you cannot get exactly the same behaviour as shown in the actual app.

Create a plain Command Line project and experiment in it. (Caution: LLDB also may keep strong reference. Do not rely on it.)

Comment: Good to know! I knew Playground kept objects around, so I was experimenting with REPL. Didn't know REPL did the same